# Возможно ли связать с сокетом, созданным с помощью socketpair и ввод и вывод процесса?

Tags: c, unix, pipes, unix-socket

МНе нужно, чтоб чтение и запись в процесс, поражденный с помощью fork()+exec производилась через 1 файловый десркиптор(по этому pipe не подходит), возможно ли в дочернем процессе переназначить и ввод и вывод на дескриптор socketpair?

Comment: непонятно, почему pipe не подходит

Comment: @user7860670, потому что требуется открыть два пайпа для двухсторонней передачи, следовательно два дескриптора

Comment: и в чем затруднение с двумя дескрипторами?